# Spark-Shell--- error: object jblas is not a member of package org (Windows)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running code in spark shell in windows

```
import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix
```

The error which I am getting is

```
error: object jblas is not a member of package org
```

I researched on stackoverflow, but answer is available for Linux system only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Innocent

Answer (score 1):

You should add jblas to your classpath when you startup spark-shell

such as:

```
bin/spark-shell --packages org.jblas:jblas:1.2.4-SNAPSHOT
```

Then, the ivy in the spark distribution will load jblas automatically.